# Native Mobile Webapp vs. Mobile Browser App from a ServerSided Point of View

Tags: mobile, native, server-side

Is there an important difference between native mobile apps and mobile browserbased webapps according to the connection to a server which e.g. calculate stuff and sends it back to the mobile device?

The reason i ask is that there is a wide range of mobile app frameworks for serverside like vert.x, node.js, spring and many more. Isnt it just regardless of which framework I use to build a server for communication with mobile devices, no matter if they use a native app or a browser-based app - assuming they are totally equal in user-interaction?

I know there are differences in "what kind of information" is transacted between server and client according to performance, speed, scalability. My question aims only to the differences of native and browserbased web apps.

I just read this post: [Server-side architecture for mobile web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746595/server-side-architecture-for-mobile-web-applications) but i guess its not satisfying my lack of knowledge because author and question-resolver both refered to UI frameworks for mobile web applications. My idea is to have one server technology which is used by a mobile browser web app and the same app as native app at the same time with the same performance results. Is that something to worry about?

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can do the client side with browser and mobile apps with the one server side stack. Choose the server side depending on your skill set or those of your partners/employees and taking account of the nature of the task including volumes.

I would go for a server side that will support restful communication as that can be used by browser or mobile apps quite easily.